# I am working on the hr leave odoo 12, xlsx report by department , I have overwrite problem when print xlsx report for more than one department

Tags: odoo

I am working on the hr leave odoo 12, xlsx report by department , I have overwrite problem when print xlsx report  for more than one department.

here is my code:

```py
############################### for department #########################################
    def get_all_date(self, data, empid):
        domain = [('state', '=', 'validate'), ('employee_id', '=', empid)]

        if data.get('date_from'):
            domain.append(('date_from', '>=', data.get('date_from')))
        if data.get('date_to'):
            domain.append(('date_from', '<=', data.get('date_to')))
        print(domain)

        leave = self.env['hr.leave'].search(domain)
        return leave

    

    

    def generate_xlsx_report(self, workbook, data, record):

        #####################  for department ########
        res = []
        Employee = self.env['hr.employee']
        if 'depts' in data:
            for department in self.env['hr.department'].browse(data['depts']):
                res.append(
                    {
                        'dept': department.name,
                        'data': []
                    }
                )
                for emp in Employee.search([('department_id', '=', department.id)]):
                    res[len(res) - 1]['data'].append(
                        {
                            # 'emp': emp.name,
                            'display': self.get_all_date(data['data'], emp.id)

                        }

                    )

                sheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Leaves Report')
        bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'align': 'center', 'bg_color': '#fffbed', 'border': True})
        format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'd-m-yyyy'})
        header_row_style = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'align': 'center', 'border': True})
        format2 = workbook.add_format({'font_size': 10, 'bold': True, 'align': 'center', })
        title = workbook.add_format(
            {'bold': True, 'align': 'center', 'font_size': 20, 'bg_color': '#f2eee4', 'border': True})

        sheet.merge_range('A1:E1', 'Leaves Summary Report', title)

        # Header row

        # Header row
        sheet.set_column(0, 4, 18)
        sheet.write(2, 0, 'Department', header_row_style)
        sheet.write(3, 1, 'Employee', header_row_style)
        sheet.write(3, 2, ' Start date', header_row_style)
        sheet.write(3, 3, 'End date', header_row_style)
        sheet.write(3, 4, 'Leave Type', header_row_style)


        ######################### for department #############################

        for rows, i in enumerate(res):
            print(i)
            col=0
            sheet.write(rows + 4, col, i['dept'], format2)
            #rows+1
            for j in i['data']:
                print(j)
                for rows ,k in enumerate(j['display']):
                    print(k)
                # sheet.write(ro + 3, col, k.department_id.name, format2)
                    sheet.write(rows + 4, col + 1, k.employee_id.name, format2)
                    sheet.write(rows + 4, col + 2, k.date_from, format)
                    sheet.write(rows+ 4, col + 3, k.date_to, format)
                    sheet.write(rows + 4, col + 4, k.holiday_status_id.name, format2)
                    rows+ 1
```

Comment: Are there more details? Please add them. Do you get errors? Or do you just get a wrong behaviour. Just showing a lot of code won't get someone helping you.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).